# Beautiful soup extract multiple links if avaliable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would link to scan the page listed below and extract the 2 download links it provides. I cant use the tag names as they will always change. Also there are times when there is only 1 link. The code errors because it says there is no "a" attribute. There is but not sure how to traverse 3 nodes down.

```
    <ul class="field__items">
        <li class="field__item">
           <div class="media media--type-zip media--view-mode-file-list">
               <a href="/files/zip/pdp-enrollment-statecountycontract-january-2020-full-version.zip">PDP Enrollment by State/County/Contract – January 2020 - Full version (ZIP)</a>
        </div>
    </li>
                                <li class="field__item">

    <div class="media media--type-zip media--view-mode-file-list">
      
                <a href="/files/zip/pdp-enrollment-statecountycontract-january-2020-abridged-version-exclude-rows-10-or-less-enrollees.zip">PDP Enrollment by State/County/Contract – January 2020 - Abridged version to exclude rows with 10 or less enrollees (ZIP)</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from lxml import html
import requests

def http_request_get(url, session=None, payload=None, parse=True):
""" Sends a GET HTTP request to a website and returns its HTML content and full url address. """

if payload is None:
  payload = {}

if session:
   content = session.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',"content-type":"text"})
else:
   content = requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',"content-type":"text"})

content.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad requests (4xx or 5xx)

if parse:
   return BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser'), content.url
else:
   return content.text, content.url

def get_html(link):
 """
 Returns a html.
 """
page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=link, payload={'t': ''}, parse=True)
 return page_parsed


cmslink =  'https://www.cms.gov/research-statistics-data-and-systemsstatistics-trends-and-reportsmcradvpartdenroldatamonthly-pdp/pdp-enrollment-scc-2020-01'

df = pd.DataFrame()
content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
table = content.find("div", class_="field__items").a['href']
```

Comment: `content.find("div", class_="field__items")` I don't see any div tags with that class?  The only tag I see with that class is `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are searching which is with ul tag **Not** div tag.

To get all `href` value use this.This will store all `href` value in a list.

```
table =[ a['href'] for a in content.find("ul", class_="field__items").find_all('a')]
print(table)
```